# row counter for html table row

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces, jstl

I have HTML table in JSF web application. I am generating rows dynamically using `<ui:repeat>`. I want a counter for each row. How can I get this? Any help?

Ssimilar to rowKeyVar in rich faces dataTable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are using richfaces, you can do it with its iteration tag (`<a4j:repeat>`), which is a bit more appropriate than using `<c:forEach>`, and which is like an extension to `<ui:repeat>`

```
<table>
    <a4j:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item" rowKeyVar="idx">
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{idx + 1}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{item.someProperty}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{item.otherProperty}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </a4j:repeat>
</table>
```

Answer (score 21):

As of Facelets 2.0, this is now possible using the `varStatus`.

```
<ui:repeat varStatus="status" var="user" value="#{collection}">
     #{status.index}
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't do it nicely with the `ui:repeat`, but you can do so with the `h:dataTable`. Bind the component to a [`UIData`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) property in the backing bean. It has a [`getRowIndex()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex%28%29) method which does exactly what you need:

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{bean.table}" value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{bean.table.rowIndex + 1}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{item.someProperty}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{item.otherProperty}" /></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Here I am adding `1` to `UIData#getRowIndex()` because it is zero-based. You may find the [Using datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) article useful to learn more about datatables.

If you actually want a bit more control over the table layout (especially using colspans/rowspans, which are lacking in the real JSF `h:dataTable` tag), then an alternative is to use the JSTL [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag which has a `varStatus` attribute which gives you a handle to the loop status.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{loop.index + 1}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{item.someProperty}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{item.otherProperty}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I will try the second approach. c:forEach. Thanks BalusC

Comment: The major disadvantage of `c:forEach` is that you cannot use input components in the table easily. With a `h:dataTable` you can easily create an editable datatable and JSF will manage all the data collecting and updating fully itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no counter for each row in ui:repeat. As BalusC said you can go for h:datatable. Another idea is indirectly you can add a additional index method in bean for each object in the list in serverside and get that in jsf and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

A bad (or good idea) is using **JavaScript** to do that trick.

```
<script>
    var numberOfIndex = 0;
</script>
<ui:repeat value="#{modelBean.listUser}" var="item">
    <tr>
            <td><script>numberOfIndex -=-1;document.write(numberOfIndex);</script></td>
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```