# Replace c:foreach on ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

I use JSF2 and primefaces. I have this piece of code

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="i">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{i} #{msg.set}:"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Is it possible replace with ui:repeat without creating list items in range from 1 to 5?

Comment: pls check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7768050/757071

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to get away with constructing an inline list with spel

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

```
<ui:repeat var="i" value="#{1,2,3,4,5}">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{i} #{msg.set}:"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

But may be unwieldy if you need hundreds.

I think you would have to create a backing bean of some sort to be more flexible.

It could be made as a seperate utility bean that has a method the returns a List of integers i guess to help out so you could call

```
<ui:repeat var="i" value="#{util.generate(1,5)}">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{i} #{msg.set}:"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The ui:repeat tag is not a general iterating tag, but works with collections only.

You'll have to use forEach, or design around this.